# Sorting ItemsControl in WPF fastest way

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

Sorting takes a lot of time to finish .
I am using an ItemsControl WPF element to show a list of items ( An observable Collection) and i want to sort this Observable Collection based on a property
I used this code for doing the sort operation

```
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mycontrolName.ItemsSource);
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("Property", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
        dataView.Refresh();
```

But its taking a lot of time to reflect the changes on UI. Once i click the sort button it took almost 8-10 seconds to render the sorted view . 
Any idea to improve this perfomance ( My list contains more than 100 items and every list item consists of some images and few text properties ).

The xaml i used is

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ShelfItemsCollection}" Name="shelfGridView" Margin="5" Visibility="Collapsed"VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"   VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate> 
        <Border Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=shelfBorderStyle}" MinWidth="200">
  <Stackpanel>
 <Image Width="150" Height="200" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding CoverImage}" ></Image> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  MaxWidth="150"></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  MaxWidth="150"  ></TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: You need UI virtualization. Post the relevant XAML.

Comment: You could try `IEnumerable<YourDataType> sortedCollection = collection.OrderBy(i => i.Property);`. You'll need to add `System.Linq using`.

Comment: @JMat cannot view pastebin, please include in your question.

Comment: @HighCore Xaml is added to question and i use a button to initiate sort action

Comment: @HighCore https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=529BE5C1D41B4A28%21230
A sample project is added here that explains problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorting 100 item based on a single property could probably never take 8-10 seconds on today's processors, there is something seriously wrong with the view.

if I am not wrong and it is related to your previous question. follow the steps below

- remove `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` from the main listbox if it is there.
- add `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` to the listbox
- also add `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` to the same listbox

this will definitely solve the rendering issue

image loading issue

- you need to defer the loading of external images or load them asynchronously
- you may show a placeholder while image is loading
- also suggested do not load all the images while populating the collection, only load when it is required to be on the view.

**Update**

I found an issue in your code, it is due to incompatible type of a property `Progress` in `LocalLibrary`.

this property is bound to progress-bar's value property which is of type double and in model this property as defined as string.

this cause an exception while data conversion, also slows down adding, sorting, removal etc. more the items more are exceptions, and while debugging such exceptions are logged in output window so delay is even more.

original error from output window, this is a good source of debugging wpf issues.

`'SystemConvertConverter' converter failed to convert value '<null>' (type '<null>'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Progress; DataItem='LocalLibrary' (HashCode=46519225); target element is 'ProgressBar' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Double') InvalidCastException:'System.InvalidCastException: Null object cannot be converted to a value type.`

so by changing this property alone to a compatible type ie. double will improve performance significantly

```
    private double progress { get; set; }

    public double Progress
    {
        get { return progress; }
        set
        {
            progress = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried all these suggestions but not much difference in perfomance. The xaml and code i am using is here http://pastebin.com/Ndrkhqtq

Comment: Any updates on this? I tried with a simple itemscontrol and sorting is much faster. Is it because of triggers and StatuicResourceStyles assigned on the controls?

Comment: did you try to defer the image loading also?

Comment: Yes i tried list without images too. Still the performance is same.

Comment: As you've tried most of the possible approach, so now I could only say something after I debug the same. So is it possible for you to send me a strip down version of your working code? that code should be able to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: You can download the sample project from here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=529BE5C1D41B4A28%21230
As you can see if you increase no of items to big value , the time taken for sorting also gets increased

Comment: Another interesting point to note here , If i run  the exe i can see sort time is very less.Only while running frm Visual studio it takes a long time

Comment: Yes that was the issue and is solved. Just a question to ask here "error from output window, this is a good source of debugging wpf issues". How can i see this in detail while debuggin in visual studio

Comment: once you are debugging an app in visual studio go to VS and select menu View->Output (Ctrl W+O for C#), and you'll find a window with couple of information in it. this information include binding issues, conversion issues, exceptions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mycontrolName.ItemsSource);
    using(dataView.DeferRefresh())
    {
       dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
       SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("Property", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
       dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
    }
```

I suspect some of the slow down is because you are in effect refreshing the view 3 times.

1. `dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();`
2. `dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);`
3. `dataView.Refresh();`

DeferRefresh will reduce that to a single refresh. Still that should only reduce it down to about 2second...which is still pretty damned slow.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx#remarksToggle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#remarksToggle)

Comment: I tried this way , But i cnat see any big difference

Comment: @JMat I cannot access pastebin due to firewall issues. PLEASE post your code in your question!

Comment: Its added in question

Comment: A sample project that explains problem is attached here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=529BE5C1D41B4A28%21230